# How can I substring word in C#

Tags: c#

How can I substring word in C#?
for example
this my Sentence
"This is an example summary that we are using as an example."

i want substring 2 word=
"this is"

Comment: What are the criteria by which you find your substring? If it is always the constant `this is`, why not assign that as a literal to a string directly: `string mySubString = "this is";`?

Comment: I'd love to see what you tried before asking.

Comment: It's really absolutely not clear, what your goal is. It would be great, if you gave a response to what O.R.Mapper said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is using `string.Split()` to split the words by white-space, take two words via `Enumerable.Take` and then [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) them with white-spaces again:

```
string firstTwoWords = string.Join(" ", text.Split().Take(2));
```

Remember to add `using System.Linq;`

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/QQEioP)